# Android a lot of information on one screen - how to simplify?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am new to Android development. I am working on application where Sql-lite is also involved, its a database application. The application is used on Android Tablets

In of the screen we have a lot of "related information", nearly 100 different controls (Text Data, DateTime Data, Selection list) are used to load that data, the user enters the data & can perform the CRUD operations on it. Currently i am using the ScrollView Layout as the main container for that screen.

The application is running smoothly no performance issue but the users saying we are tired of scrolling up & down all the time.

1- I need your suggestions how to resolve this issue?

2- Should i divide the information into more than one screen & what is the best solution? (For example each screen can have Forward Backward Arrows etc.)

Thanks for your valuable time & help.

Comment: This is really a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)? It gives a really nice, clean way of organising lots of options or data and you can define sub PreferenceScreens in the XML layout which are perfect for grouping large chuncks of options/data, or a couple of smaller groups, together. This way you can easily hide away bits that you don't need.